# Node js https сервер не открывается на мобильных устройствах

Tags: node.js, http, express, https

Стоит сайт на vps, отлично работает с ПК но при попытке открыть его с телефона выдает ошибку. Так же не работают http запросы.

Как запускается сервер:

```
httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('private.key'), // путь к ключу
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.crt'), // путь к сертификату
};

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(443, () => {
      console.log('App has been started on port:' + PORT);
});
```

Насколько я понял нужно поставить редирект с http на https, но с моей реализацией все равно не работает

Моя реализация

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.secure) {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```

Подскажите возможно есть другой способ это сделать. Возможно дополнительно включить http сервер который будет отправлять запросы на https?

Answer (score 0):

UPD: Все решилось банальным добавлением http сервера

```
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(443);
```